# FItNesse: Convert Fit fixture to Slim

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Looking for a solution to convert Fit fixture for FitNesse test to Slim.

I got the Command-Line [Fit fixture](http://fit.c2.com/wiki.cgi?CommandLineFixture).

Since all my Fitnesse test system is running on Slim I need to have `CommandLineFixture` as Slim to execute bash script from my test.

Any other workaround for this should work for me.

I am trying to execute a script from FitNesse test and this script writes some text in file present in a server where my Fitnesse server is running.

But what I am observing with the [provided fixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/fixture/slim/ExecuteProgramTest.java) its opening file and not writing any text into it.

So just wanted to check do we have any constraint with Fitnesse to execute a script which writes into a file.

Also, I have given all `rwx` permission to the text file

Below is my modified script:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} 
!path ../fixtures/*.jar  
|Import                                            |  
| nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.ExecuteProgramTest | 
|script                                            | 
|set    |-c            |as argument|0              |  
|set    |ls -l /       |as argument|1              |  
|execute|/bin/bash                                 |  
|check  |exit code     |0                          |  
|show   |standard out                              |  
|check  |standard error|!--!                       |
```

Executing the above test fetched no response and gives the result as:

> Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 1 ignored, 0 exceptions
>
> Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions
>
> (0.456 seconds)

Comment: I believe you have to remove the '.ExecuteProgramTest' from the line below import. Then a blank line must be added above the line with 'script' and at the end of the line with script should become `|script|ExecuteProgramTest|` . That should fix the test.

Comment: Thank you for patiently helping me out of this.

Comment: If it helped can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a helper method to start a program in my [my fixture library](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) already, but I started work on fixture today. Would the [execute program test](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/hsac/fitnesse/fixture/slim/ExecuteProgramTest.java) fixture work for you?

Example usage:

We can run a program with some arguments, check its exit code and show its output.

```
|script |execute program test        |
|set    |-c            |as argument|0|
|set    |ls -l /       |as argument|1|
|execute|/bin/bash                   |
|check  |exit code     |0            |
|show   |standard out                |
|check  |standard error|!--!         |
```

The default timeout for program execution is one minute, but we can set a custom timeout. Furthermore we can control the directory it is invoked from, set all arguments using a list and get its output 'unformatted'.

```
|script               |execute program test           |
|check                |timeout           |60000       |
|set timeout of       |100               |milliseconds|
|set working directory|/                              |
|set                  |-c, ls -l         |as arguments|
|execute              |/bin/bash                      |
|check                |exit code         |0           |
|show                 |raw standard out               |
|check                |raw standard error|!--!        |
```

The timeout can also be set in seconds, and pass environment variables (and the process's output is escaped to ensure it is displayed properly).

```
|script        |execute program test           |
|set timeout of|1              |seconds        |
|set value     |Hi <there>     |for        |BLA|
|set           |-c             |as argument|0  |
|set           |!-echo ${BLA}-!|as argument|1  |
|execute       |/bin/bash                      |
|check         |exit code      |0              |
|check         |raw standard out               |!-Hi <there>
-!|
|check|standard out|{{{Hi <there>
}}}|
```

Comment: I have used provided library which didnt work. Below is script that I am trying to execute:!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path /home/fixtures/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures-2.11.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
|Import                         |
| nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.ExecuteProgramTest |
than above one of the code provided.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the import table should only contain the package name, not the class. Can you try that? If that doesn't help can you share what error occurs?

Comment: And I believe you'll need to add more jars to the path: the dependencies used by the library. I usually do this via the maven-classpath-pluging (e.g. `!pomFile ../pom.xml@compile`), or by having Maven copy all my dependencies to a directory (e.g. fixtures) and then using `!path fixtures/*.jar`.

Comment: Good to know this one. I am trying to execute script from Fitnesse test and this script writes some text in file present in server where my Fitnesse is running. But what I am observing is its opening file and not writing any text into it. So just wanted to check do we have any constraint with Fitnesse to execute a script which writes into a file.  Also I have given all rwx permission to file.

Comment: !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!path ../fixtures/*.jar
|Import                         |
| nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.ExecuteProgramTest |
|script |
|set    |-c            |as argument|0|
|set    |ls -l /       |as argument|1|
|execute|/bin/bash                   |
|check  |exit code     |0            |
|show   |standard out                |
|check  |standard error|!--!         |
Executing above test fetched no response. and give result as: Test Pages: 0 right, 0 wrong, 1 ignored, 0 exceptions     Assertions: 0 right, 0 wrong, 0 ignored, 0 exceptions (0.456 seconds)

Comment: Can you add this to the question? In a comment without formatting I can't see what is going on. Or maybe post it as issue on the project's GitHub

Comment: Added this to question above